# Error response from daemon: Get https://x.x.x.x/v1/users/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, authentication, docker-ucp, dtr

I'm new in docker and I testing some stuffs. I had installed a UCP to upload my images but when I wanted login to UCP with CLI showed this error:

> Error response from daemon: Get https://x.x.x.x/v1/users/: x509:
>   certificate signed by unknown authority

I searched this error and I found many responses (many differents responses) after that, I finished to install the DTR and I could login without a problem.

My questions is:

After I had installed just the UCP I tried connect to this, the error showed. So, Is necessary have installed DTR to correctly connect?, or, Could it be another problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

" I had installed a UCP to upload my images". What does this mean? The DTR should be part of your UCP Swarm and that is where you push your images to.
So if you are getting this error when trying to push your image to one of the repository in DTR, then try the below steps(assuming your worker nodes are window 2016 servers).

1. Create certificate in DTR node
2. Copy the certificate to the docker node or which ever machine from which you are trying to push the image
3. Open MMC
4. Add certificates (use Computer account)
5. Open Trusted Root Certification Authorities
6. Click More action on the right and click import
7. Upload the copied certificate and finish
8. Try "docker login" command with your DTR url and make sure you able to login without an issue